# Visual Studio publish doesn't actually publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish

I have several MVC3 applications, when I try and publish it doesn't actually publish anything, the output is:

```
2>obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.
2>Deleting existing files...
2>Publishing folder /...
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

Change publish mode from RELEASE to DEBUG (or vice versa), publish, change again and publish again.